# How do I get virtualfish to work on OSx

Tags: macos, fish, virtualfish

I have cloned virtualfish to my ~/clones/virtualfish

and as per the docs it says source virtual.fish from the above cloned directory of virtualfish inside ~/.config/fish/config.fish

Noting given on http://virtualfish.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html works !

Do I need to be in fish prompt or have it installed ?

how do I even know that fish is using .config/local/config.fish ?

how do I get bashrc and bash_profile to load up in fish prompt then ?

Comment: This is better suited for http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: is their a way to move post across ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, virtualfish is designed for the fish prompt, and so it's assumed you have it installed and are using it. If you want to use bash, you should use virtualenv instead.

The fish prompt does not use .bashrc or .bash_profile, as these are of course bash-specific.